# AngularJs ng-repeat in Yii2 Grid column

Tags: angularjs, yii2, yii2-grid

I need to embed a small HTML snippet in a column of a Yii2 GridView. The HTML contains angular directives (i.e., ng-repeat). Here is the GridView column:

```
                [
                    'label' => 'Column',
                    'format' => 'html',
                    'value' => function ($model) {
                        $return = '';
                        $return.= '<div ng-repeat="el in elements">';
                        $return.= '<h4>El Title: {{el.title}}</h4>';
                        $return.= '</div>';

                        return $return;
                    }
                ],
```

The GridView is inside an angular controller that should compile it when the page is rendered. However, the `ng-repeat` loops is ignored, while the `{{el-title}}` expression is evaluated empty (which tells me that angular compiled `{{el.title}}` but could not deal with the `ng-repeat`.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Show code of `ng-controller` please

Comment: Well the ng-controller does not do any special operation. I just wrapped the grid inside the controller then I guess it should compile the yii2 grid by itself when the page is rendered, like with standard html, am I wrong?

Comment: I suppose you should have `$scope.elements` with data somewhere in your ng-controller

Comment: Yes, actually '$scope.elements' is built dynamically by another section of the same page. This is done after the grid is rendered.

Comment: I believe you need `$scope.elements` should be accessible before grid is rendered